# How did the Fried Liver Attack get its name?

Tags: opening, terminology, fried-liver-attack

Many chess openings get their name from a player who invented it and/or played it and/or documented it. Place names are also frequently used, denoting where an opening was first played or became prominent, or perhaps where players who used it were from. Other openings may take their name from some sort of description of style or some other feature of the opening.

The [Fried Liver Attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_Knights_Defense,_Fried_Liver_Attack) doesn't seem to follow any of these patterns. Where does the name come from?

Comment: As anyone who's watched Ben Finegold will know, it was named after the person who popularised it - Mr Attack

Comment: From a complete noob - is this different from "Liver and Onions" moves?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: I'm not familiar with "Liver and Onions" moves. However, I've added a link in the post to the Wikipedia page on the Fried Liver Attack. Are these the same moves?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the Wikipedia article on the [Fried Liver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_Knights_Defense,_Fried_Liver_Attack),

> Italian way of cooking liver ("Fegatello" means to put the liver in a
>   net and cook it over a fire, or, in modern times, in a pan. Here we
>   can see a metaphor for what happens to Black’s king in this line: it
>   is cooked like a "fegatello". Usually Black’s king is caught in the
>   mating net and White increases the heat move by move – "dead as a
>   piece of liver".)

Comment: In Spanish, it's still known as "Fegatello"

Comment: In French too we call it "Fegatello". "Fried Liver Attack" is just a weird attempt at translating.